# shell test operator regular expressions

Tags: regex, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
# This file will fix the cygwin vs linux paths and load programmer's notepad under windows.
# mail : <sandundhammikaperera@gmail.com> 
# invokes the GNU GPL, all rights are granted.


# check first parameter is non empty.
# if empty then give a error message and exit.
file=${1:?"Usage: pn filename"};

if [[ "$file" == /*/* ]] ;then
  #if long directory name.
# :FAILTHROUGH:
  echo "$0: Executing pn.exe $file" 

else 
  file="$(pwd)/$file";
fi

#check whether the filename starts with / if so replace it with appropriate prefix #
prefix="C:/cygwin/";

#check for the partterns starting with "/" #
echo $var | grep "^/*$"
if [[ "$?" -eq "0" ]] ;then
  # check again whether parttern starts with /cygdrive/[a-z]/ parttern #
  if [[ $file == /cygdrive/[a-z]/* ]] ; then 
    file=${file#/cygdrive/[a-z]/};
    file="C:/"$file;
  else
    file="$prefix""$file";  
  fi 
fi


#check for the appropriate file permissions #
# :TODO: 


echo $file
exec "/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Programmer's Notepad/pn.exe"  $file
```

as I in my program which convert path names between cygwin and windows and load
the pn.exe [ programmer's notepad in windows]. So my questions are,

1. There are built in regex expression for the "[[" or 'test' operator. (as well as
   I used them in my above program). But why they don't work in here if I change,

   ```
   echo $var | grep "^/*$"
   if [[ "$?" -eq "0" ]] ;then
   ```

   to this,

   ```
   if [[ "$file" == ^/*$ ]] ;then
   ```

   What is the reason for that? Is there any workaround?
   I have already tried the second method `[[ "$file" == ^/*$ ]]` but it didn't work.
   then , simple googling brought to me here: [http://unix.com/shell-programming](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/66216-compare-variable-against-regular-expression.html)
2. How to find all the documentation about [[ operator or 'test' command? I have used 
   `man test` but :(. Which document specifies it's limitations on regex usage if there so.

Comment: possible duplicate of [use regular expression in if-condition in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348379/use-regular-expression-in-if-condition-in-bash)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, `grep "^/*$"` will only match paths containing only slashes, like "/", "///", "////". You can use `grep "^/"` to match paths starting with a slash. If you want to use bash regexes:

```
var="/some"
#echo $var | grep "^/"
if [[ "$var" =~ ^/ ]] ;then
  echo "yes"
fi
```

Comment: Ya that works on cygwin sehll, but the problem remains, I think I missing something. you mean `[[ "$var" =~ ^/ ]]` , what that =~ means?where to find the specification?

Comment: oky sir , it's bash built in regular comparision operator as in here: 
http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-regular-expressions

Thanks for the idea.

Comment: oky I got it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348379/use-regular-expression-in-if-condition-in-bash : sorry asking :POSSIBLE DUPLICATE: