# Regex and if in shell script

Tags: regex, shell, sed, ksh

my programs starts some services and store its output in `tmp` variable and I want to match the variable's content if it starts with `FATAL` keyword or not? and if it contains I will print `Port in use` using `echo` command

For example if `tmp` contains `FATAL: Exception in startup, exiting.`

I can do it by `sed`: `echo $tmp | sed 's/^FATAL.*/"Port in use"/'`

but I want to use the builtin `if` to match the pattern.
How can I use the shell built in features to match REGEX?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142092/shell-test-operator-regular-expressions `if [[ $tmp =~ ^FATAL.* ]]; then echo "a"; else echo "b"; fi`

Comment: Which shell? The answer for `bash` will be different from the answer for `csh` or `dash` and maybe from `ksh` too.  The comment from @Sithsu applies to `bash`, for example; the answer with `case` will work with shells derived from the Bourne/POSIX shell (not C shell derivatives).

Comment: Though this question was here earlier, this one has gathered more answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115121/how-to-check-pattern-match-by-using-bin-sh-not-by-bin-bash. If you don't want `bash`-isms, that's the question to go to. `bash` has its own tool for pattern matching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

POSIX shell doesn't have a regular expression operator for UNIX ERE or PCRE. But it does have the [`case` keyword](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_04_05):

```
case "$tmp" in
  FATAL*) doSomethingDrastic;;
  *) doSomethingNormal;;
esac
```

You didn't tag the question `bash`, but if you do have that shell you can do some other kinds of pattern matching or even ERE:

```
if [[ "$tmp" = FATAL* ]]; then
    …
fi
```

or

```
if [[ $tmp =~ ^FATAL ]]; then
    …
fi
```

Comment: What's the difference between the second and third answers?

Comment: @M_E The second answer uses the `[[` keyword that is similar to the `test` command but has extra features including `case`-like pattern matching. The third answer uses ERE (extended regular expressions).

Answer (score 1):

```
if [ -z "${tmp%FATAL*}" ]
   then echo "Start with"
 else 
   echo "Does not start with"
 fi
```

work on KSH, BASH under AIX. Think it's also ok under Linux.

It's **not a real regex** but the limited regex used for file matching (internal to the shell, not like sed/grep/... that have their own version inside) of the shell. So * and ? could be used