# How to test if string matches a regex in POSIX shell? (not bash)

Tags: regex, shell, sh, posix

I'm using Ubuntu system shell, not bash, and I found the regular way can not work:

```
#!/bin/sh
string='My string';

if [[ $string =~ .*My.* ]]
then
   echo "It's there!"
fi
```

error [[: not found!

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The `[[ ... ]]` are a bash-ism.  You can make your test shell-agnostic by just using `grep` with a normal `if`:

```
if echo "$string" | grep -q "My"; then
    echo "It's there!"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I need, and I also realized what is the bashism:http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism

Answer (score 29):

Using **grep** for such a simple pattern can be considered wasteful. Avoid that unnecessary **fork**, by using the Sh built-in Glob-matching engine (NOTE: This does **not**  support regex):

```
case "$value" in
  *XXX*)  echo OK ;;
  *) echo fail ;;
esac
```

It is POSIX compliant. Bash have [simplified syntax](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern) for this:

```
if [[ "$value" == *XXX* ]]; then :; fi
```

and even regex:

```
[[ abcd =~ b.*d ]] && echo ok
```

Answer (score 13):

You could use `expr`:

```
if expr "$string" : "My" 1>/dev/null; then
  echo "It's there";
fi
```

This would work with both `sh` and `bash`.

As a handy function:

```
exprq() {
  local value

  test "$2" = ":" && value="$3" || value="$2"
  expr "$1" : "$value" 1>/dev/null
}

# Or `exprq "somebody" "body"` if you'd rather ditch the ':'
if exprq "somebody" : "body"; then 
  echo "once told me"
fi
```

Quoting from `man expr`:

```
   STRING : REGEXP
          anchored pattern match of REGEXP in STRING
```

Comment: This is the traditional, portable solution if you really require regular exoressiins. However, a lot of the time, `case` is sufficient; and `grep` gets the job done as well, and is probably more familiar to most users.

Comment: expr is build in to Bourne shell and much faster, we should favor this over other methods.

Comment: All well and good if you **always want to match at the beginning of the string**, otherwise it won't work (why the heck did they put that restriction in?) - and BTW this answer does not satisfy the OP's specific case, matching **anywhere in the string**.

Comment: @user9645 Calm down. expr takes a regular expression, which is exactly what the OP asked for. You can search practically anything.

Comment: But, @user9645 is correct.  The regex in the question includes a leading and trailing `.*`, which you have removed in your answer, implying they weren't necessary, but without the leading `.*`, it fails.