# What is the regex matching operator in bourne shell script?

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I am trying to validate user input against a regular expression.

```
vari=A
if [ $vari =~ [A-Z] ] ;
then
    echo "hurray"
fi
```

The output I am getting is swf.sh[3]: =~: unknown test operator.

Can you please let me know the test operator I can use?

Comment: Aside: `/bin/sh` on systems from the last 15 years (at least) is POSIX sh, not Bourne.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check pattern match by using /bin/sh, not by /bin/bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115121/how-to-check-pattern-match-by-using-bin-sh-not-by-bin-bash)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not built into Bourne shell, you need to use grep:

```
if echo "$vari" | grep -q '[A-Z]'; then
    echo hurray
fi
```

If you want to match the whole string, remember to use the regex anchors, `^` and `$`. Note that the `-q` flag makes grep quiet, so its only output is the return value, for match/not match.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. However, it's not clear that he's using bash. I haven't done extensive programming in Bourne shell, but using grep will work in almost any bash-like shell. If the actual Bourne shell does support the `=~` operator, color me surprised.

Answer (score 5):

POSIX shell doesn't have a regular expression operator (or rather, the POSIX `test` command does not). Instead, you use the `expr` command to do a (limited) form of regular expression matching.

```
if expr "$vari" : '[A-Z]' > /dev/null; then
```

(I say "limited" because it always matches at the beginning of the string, as if the regular expression started with `^`.) The exit status is 0 if a match is made; it also writes the number of characters matched to standard output, hence the redirect to `/dev/null`.

If you are actually using `bash`, you need to use the `[[` command:

```
if [[ $vari =~ [A-Z] ]]; then
```