# test for regex in string with a posix shell

Tags: regex, shell, posix

how can I test if a string matches a particular string matches regex with a basic (no bash or anything) posix shell script (in an if statement)?

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21115121/537554

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test if string matches a regex in POSIX shell? (not bash)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115121/how-to-test-if-string-matches-a-regex-in-posix-shell-not-bash)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `expr` command to evaluate regular expression in a POSIX shell:

```
s='Abc'
expr $s : '^[[:alpha:]]\+'

3
```

`expr` returns # of matched characters which is 3 in this case.

Comment: Caveat: for `expr`, a ‘^’ is implicitly prepended, also the regex has to be in the basic form.