# How to check if a string is a substring of another?

Tags: string, shell

I have the following strings in bash

```
str1="any string"
str2="any"
```

I want to check if `str2` is a substring of `str1`

I can do it in this way:

```
c=`echo $str1 | grep $str2`
if [ $c != "" ]; then
    ...
fi
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use wild-card expansion `*`.

```
str1="any string"
str2="any"

if [[ "$str1" == *"$str2"* ]]
then
  echo "str2 found in str1"
fi
```

Note that `*` expansion will not work with single `[ ]`.

Comment: Are the quotes necessary in this case? I thought one of the main advantages of `[[]]` over `[]` was making quoting unnecessary...

Comment: True. It bites if I miss one when it's necessary but an extra doesn't hurt.  It's one of those things I force myself to do it always ;-)

Comment: Disclaimer: That wasn't me. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar hehe..I know it's not you :)

Answer (score 3):

```
str1="any string"
str2="any"
```

Old school (Bourne shell style):

```
case "$str1" in *$str2*)
    echo found it
esac
```

New school (as speakr shows), however be warned that the string to the right will be viewed as a regular expression:

```
if [[ $str1 =~ $str2 ]] ; then
    echo found it
fi
```

But this will work too, even if you're not exactly expecting it:

```
str2='.*[trs].*'
if [[ $str1 =~ $str2 ]] ; then
    echo found it
fi
```

Using `grep` is slow, since it spawns a separate process.

Comment: +1 for the `case` expression. But that's not old-school, it's the **current state-of-the-art** since it's as POSIXly portable as it gets. BTW, no need to quote $str1; there's no word splitting done after a `case`.

Comment: I wouldn't assume all existing Unix hosts are current with the POSIX standard.  That case expression is compatible with much older systems than the [[ ... =~ ...  ]] syntax - decades older.  Therefore *much* more portable.

Comment: Then we're in violent agreement. The `case` way of looking for substrings works with any Bourne shell, so is state-of-the-art and to be unconditionally preferred. Anyone using bashisms like `[[ ]]` is in need for a portability lesson. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use bash regexp matching without using `grep`:

```
if [[ $str1 =~ $str2 ]]; then
    ...
fi
```

Note that you don't need any surrounding slashes or quotes for the regexp pattern. If you want to use glob pattern matching just use `==` instead of `=~` as operator.

Some examples can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2348495/1337398).

Answer (score 0):

```
if echo $str1 | grep -q $str2    #any command 
   then
   .....
fi
```