# Why "if [[ ${value} == ^[[:blank:]]*$ ]]" cannot detect empty variable?

Tags: bash, shell

I tried the following three codes to detects empty variable.

```
unset value

if [[ -z ${value} ]]; then
  echo "value is judged as empty by [[ -z ]] : value = '${value}'"
fi

if [[ ${value} == ^[[:blank:]]*$ ]]; then
  echo "value is judged as empty by [[ == ]] : value = '${value}'"
fi

if echo ${value} | grep -E "^[[:blank:]]*$"; then
  echo "value is judged as empty by grep -E "^[[:blank:]]*$" : value = '${value}'"
fi
```

The results are following,

```
value is judged as empty by [[ -z ]] : value = ''

value is judged as empty by grep -E ^[[:blank:]]* : value = ''
```

Why the second one does not work? Please let me know.

Comment: To use a regex, use `=~`: `if [[ ${value} =~ ^[[:blank:]]*$ ]]; then`. You could also use a glob: `if [[ $value = *([[:blank:]]) ]]; then`.

Comment: -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348379/use-regular-expression-in-if-condition-in-bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second one is a pattern, not a regular expression. It only matches strings with at least 3 characters: `^`, a single blank character, zero or more arbitrary characters, and `$`. To match the regular expression representing zero or more blank characters, use the `=~` operator.

```
if [[ $value =~ ^[[:blank:]]*$ ]]; then
```

Comment: Ah, right. Those are only metacharacters in a regular expression.

Comment: thank you for answering. I did not discriminate 'pattern' and 'regular expression'.